# Tomcat sets cookie JSESSIONID spontaneously

Tags: java, spring, session, servlets, cookies

I have a spring webapp running on tomcat. I never set any sessions in my code. There is only this line :

```
HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession(false);
if( session != null )
{
     log.debug("session is not null");
}
```

These lines logs, `session is not null`, which makes no sense. I also checked, a cookie named `JSESSIONID` is being set. But as you can see above I give false `enter code here`argument to `getSession`. How is this possible ?

Comment: Simple: if you don't create it someone else does. Spring is a good candidate.

Comment: You seem right. It looks like spring creates a session. But whyyyyyy. :(

Comment: Are you using JSPs? Spring security?

Comment: You could try writing a simple session listener that writes a stacktrace to the logs on session creation that should tell you where this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the fact that unless you enter `<% session=false %>` jsp pages creates a session.